# How can I change the order of columns and concatenate certain columns in a csv file?

Tags: linux, csv, concatenation

I've been trying to figure this out for a while, but I have a csv file that has 13 columns.  I want to concatenate columns 1, 2 and 3 (having the output be "column 3, column 1 column 2").  I then want to have the columns organized 4,7,(new concatenated column),6,9,10,11,12,13,5,8.  I have found a way to use python to organize the columns, but I can't figure out how to concatenate the three fields and input that into the new csv file.  Does anyone have any idea how to do this?  I don't really care if it's in bash or python, or really anything.  I'm fairly new to Linux scripting, so I'm not partial to any specific language.

Comment: Have you read the manual for the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module?

Comment: Please include some example data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

One way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS=","; X = "\"" } { print $4, $7, X$3, $1 $2X $6, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $5, $8 }' file.txt
```

Comment: Let's hope he has no quoted fields, then.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Just a stab in the dark :-)